# Can not cast from View to ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        setTitle("First Window");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    }
```

This is my code.
R.id.List is a ListView in my .xml file.
while trying to build project i am getting error on line

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); //that is "Cannot cast from View to ListView" please help me.
```

And my XML file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: clean and build your project

Comment: Thanks dude but i am tryimg this from last 2 hours.

Comment: I had also restrat eclipse and my pc but it didn't work

Comment: post the xml activity_list_view

Comment: Does the code compile fine and then give you a ClassCastException, or is it not compiling at all?

Comment: it isn't compiling at all

Comment: @AJay post your xml code.

Comment: i just posted my xml code. check it @Raghunandan

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't extending from `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`? Typically, for `ListViews` in a _`ListActivity`_, the ID is given as `@android:id/list`, not `@+id`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see, did you import android.widget.ListView? i think you are making a class named as ListView.java in same package..

Answer (score 2):

Android has released a class extending `Activity` called `ListActivity` which already has private `ListView` inside that you can interact with using `getListView()`.
This class works if the list `id` in the xml is decalred as following:
`android:id="@android:id/list"`

More info is contained [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html):
-- There's simpler implementation about the `Adapter` using `AsyncTask` instead of threads and runnables. Read them both.

View the [Android release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: `android:id="@android:id/list"` not `@+id`, but otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView looks like :

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@android:id/list">
```

Then declare it like this :

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

It should works ;)

Comment: @AJay i don't see anything wrong. but is the xml posted `activity_list_view` ?